# Concatenate a 'space' to the end of an array

Tags: c, char, append, arrays

I am writing a code where the code behaves differently if my array does not end with an empty space. I want to check whether there is a space at the end or not. If there isn't,then i want to append a space to the end of my array. here is the code for the array.

```
char* buffer[1024];
fgets(buffer,1024,fp);
char* str = buffer+2; // don't need the first two characters
char* pch;
pch = strtok(str," ");//I am dividing the string into tokens as i need to save each word in a separate variable
.
.
.
```

So my question is, first, how do i check if the last character of `str` is a space or not?
Second, if it isn't a space, how do i append a space?

I have already tried `strcat` but I think the problem is i still can't figure out how to know whether the last character is a space or not. I know this can all be done easily with strings and vectors. But I would like a solution to my code. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the code for the splitting up of the line and counting the number of words.

```
//At the end of this while loop. ncol will contain the number of columns 
while(1){
fgets(buffer,1024,fp);
if (buffer[1] == 'C'){ // the line is #C 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
    char* str = buffer+2;

int n = strlen( str );
if(n == 0 || str[n-1] != ' ') {
str[n] = ' ';
str[n+1] = '\0';
}

  char* pch;
  pch = strtok(str," ");
  while(pch != NULL){
      ncol++;
      pch = strtok (NULL, " ");

    }
} 
if(buffer[0] == '#'){
    numHeader++;
    }
    else {break;}

}
```

Comment: Are you asking really about c++. This looks like plain c.

Comment: Since you are against using any of the C++ features here, even when they are THE solution in current form of the question, I'm going to replace [tag:c++] with [tag:c] on this one. Stop misusing tags.

Comment: I think it is better `strtok(str, " \n")` if it is for the `strtok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for your specific case

```
int n = strlen(str);
// *** RTRIM()
int idx = n-1;
for(; idx >= 0; idx--)
    if(str[idx] != '\0' && str[idx] != " " && str[idx] != '\t' && str[idx] != '\n' && str[idx] != '\r') 
        break;
str[idx + 1] = '\0';
// ***
int cnt = 0;
char* pch = strtok(str, " ");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    cnt++;
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

**EDIT** use a right side trim

Comment: To be pedantic, we should check that `n < 1023`.

Comment: @Emmet - 'technically correct' is the best kind of correct, edited.

Comment: @LastCoder Interestingly, I am using the same code. But without a space at the end of my array 'buffer', i get cnt=13, and with a space, it is cnt=14. Would really appreciate a solution of this. The reason i can't use strings or other options is because i have to be consistent with the rest of the code. And if i use string here, then i have to change a lot of other things which is a bigger problem than the current one.

Comment: @detraveller - You'll have to show us your whole function code or there's no way of knowing whats wrong. Perhaps it's a small logic mistake maybe your using the 'buffer' variable instead of your 'str' variable.

Comment: @detraveller - I think I see your issue now "#C 1" notice the space between C and 1 when you do buffer+2 your string would be " 1" this extra space at the beginning is why your getting an extra pointer from strtok. Try buffer+3 and don't bother adding an extra space at the end

Comment: @LastCoder The thing is that I want the code to output ncol = 13 always. There may or may not be a space at the end. I can write the code for a line that has no space at the end, i can write for a line that has a space at the end. But i need something that will output ncol=13 in both cases. That is why orgiinally my question was how to concatenate a space at the end because i thought if there was no space and i add a space myself, it would solve the problem.

Comment: @detraveller - If you always want the count to be 13 with or without a space, why don't you loop backwards through your buffer and search for != '\0' && != " " then add 1 to that index and put a '\0' to end the string. This will remove all whitespace after your tokens similar to a right trim.

Comment: @LastCoder How do i loop backwards? You mean i should not use strtok?

Comment: @detraveller - I updated my answer to do a right side trim of the 'str' variable this should remove any white space from the end of the string. Beyond this you'll just have to put some print statements and debug yourself.

Comment: Super!!! Thanks. This was bugging me for 3 months lol. I was about to write my supervisor I can't do it :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with C++:

```
std::string str = "bla ";
if (str[str.size()-1] != ' ')
    str.push_back(' ');
else
    //do smth
```

Comment: As i said, I do not want to use strings.

Comment: it's completely valid c++.